# Disable CXF logging for one web service

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

In my application I would like to log request and response with business logic. Application does some backend logic with SOAP communication and this is what I want to log.

Unfornatly in this same application I must serve data ( avg. is 4 request/s)
Let's say this service name is PlatformDataService.

How to turn off cxf logging for only one web service?

Enviorment:

- JDK 8
- cxf 2.7.14
- AS : Jboss EAP 6.4

I turn on login on server by:

- add logger org.apache.cxf INFO
- and system property org.apache.cxf.logging.enabled=true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend `LoggingInInterceptor` and `LoggingOutInterceptor`. Based on the `soapAction` you can ignore only logging for one service.

Extend `LoggingOutInterceptor` for all the outbound requests and override method `handleMessage` like this.

```
private boolean doNotLog=false;

public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
    TreeMap<String,List> protocolHeaders =
            (TreeMap<String, List>) message.get("org.apache.cxf.message.Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS");
    if (protocolHeaders != null) {
        List value = protocolHeaders.get("SOAPAction");
        String soapAction = value != null ? (String)value.get(0) : "";
        if (soapAction.equalIgnoreCase(YOUR_SERVICE_SOAP_ACTION)) {
            doNotLog=true;
        }
    }
    super.handleMessage(message);
}
```

Now there is one more method you have to override in the same class.

```
@Override
    protected String transform(String originalLogString) {
        if (doNotLog) {
            return null;
        }
        return originalLogString;
    }
```

For all inbound responses, extend `LoggingInInterceptor` and only override transform method. You can just check the responseType from the originalLogString and ignore it.