# Disable CXF logging for one method on web service

Tags: logging, cxf, logback

How can I disable One method logging in `cxf` interceptor?

I Can disable **all In requests** or **all Out requests**:

```
<logger name="org.apache.cxf.services.MyService.REQ_OUT" level="ERROR"/>
<logger name="org.apache.cxf.services.MyService.RESP_IN" level="ERROR"/>
```

But I can not disable logs ***on one method in MyService***

I found one answer similar to what I want: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42679515/4781349)

But it is not entirely clear. I don't know where I should override the method:

> @Override
>       protected String transform(String originalLogString) {
>           if (doNotLog) {
>               return null;
>           }
>           return originalLogString;
>       }

And I don’t know if this is a working example.

Answer (score 0):

I have read many articles and sites and have not found an answer. But by searching in the code, I found the reason and found the solution. I really don’t know how effective it is.

In the example that I wrote in my question, used old version of the logger (depricated) . In the new version `org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingInInterceptor` method `transform` does not exist

It is solution with new logger:

```
import org.apache.cxf.ext.logging.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault;
import org.apache.cxf.message.Message;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class UnpLoggingInInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor {

    private static final String GET_RESPONSE = "urn:GetResponse";

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message message) throws Fault {
        TreeMap<String, List> headers = (TreeMap<String, List>) message.get("org.apache.cxf.message.Message.PROTOCOL_HEADERS");

        if (headers != null) {
            List value = headers.get("SOAPAction");
            String soapAction = value != null ? (String) value.get(0) : "";
            if (soapAction.replace("\"", "").equalsIgnoreCase(GET_RESPONSE)) {
                isLoggingDisabledNow(message);
                return;
            }
        }
        super.handleMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `isLoggingDisabledNow(message);` seems useless to me.